# Is there a simple, NIO2 only way to convert from URL to Path

Tags: java, url, io, path, nio2

I want to copy a directory (including content) from a URL I get from

```
Some.class.getClassLoader().getResource("folder");
```

which returns either `jar:file:/D:/../some.jar!/someparent` or `file:/D:/../someparent`

I thought of a `FileSystem` (for jar intern dirs) and recursively copying with `Files.walkFileTree(..)`.

Is it possible to modify `jar:file:/D:/../some.jar!/folder` to get a FileSystem NIO2 only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I was looking for was something like:

```
JarURLConnection connection = (JarURLConnection) sourceUrl
     .openConnection();

Paths.get(connection.getJarFileURL().toURI());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    URL url = new URL("file:/C:/projektoj/ĝeneralaj");
    Path path = Paths.get(url.toURI());

C:\projektoj\ĝeneralaj
```

If the URL points into a jar/zip ("jar:file:/... .zip!.../...") then one may use the Path in the zip FileSystem, see: [java: change ZipEntry name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344065/java-change-zipentry-name)

Comment: what I got was something like: `jar:file:/D:/tester.jar!/specific`

Comment: Linked to another answer of interest.

Answer (score 0):

In reality, NIO.2 is really just a convenient label for new NIO features added in the Java 7 overhaul.  That is ... unless you are placing some other meaning on the term.

If you want a solution that doesn't involve anything that is not NIO.2, then (strictly speaking) that is not possible.  Any solution will involve using `String`, and `String` predates NIO.2.  It is therefore "not NIO.2"

If alternatively, you are going to allow use of classes that are in NIO.2 but not NIO, then `File` is neither NIO.2 or NIO.  It predates both of them.

---

> Is it possible to modify `"jar:file:/D:/../some.jar!/folder"` to get a FileSystem NIO2 only?

If you are asking if it is possible to create a `FileSystem` provider that could handle that, the answer is Yes in theory, and it has probably already been done ... modulo restrictions on what you can do to a JAR file.  (In-place update via the Path / FileSystem would be really difficult to implement, and expensive in terms of runtime resources.)

If you are constraining the above problem by saying that only NIO.2 APIs should be used to implement the provider and/or use it, then the answer is probably No.  (But it depends on what you really mean by "only NIO.2" ... and that depends on what you are *really* trying to achieve ...)

Comment: Technically, I think Sun previewed `Paths` and friends in a late point release to Java 6, but for all intents and purposes 7 was the "real" release.

Comment: non NIO2 not because of `Paths` but because of `File`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at :
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathClass.html

> Version Note: If you have pre-JDK7 code that uses java.io.File, you
>   can still take advantage of the Path class functionality by using the
>   File.toPath method. See Legacy File I/O Code for more information.

Edited:
I guess `File.toPath()` method should be what you want, it returns a `Path`, in this case `Paths.get(URI)` is not necessary.

Edit again:
You can take advantage of `Paths.get(URL.toURI())` if you start with an URL, but need to handle `URISyntaxException` thrown from URL.toURI().

As mentioned by @Stephen C, `Path` is a nio2 feature.